# Server calls back client in an asynchrounus mode once the processing is done

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

We have a heavy processing which we decided to put it in an asynchronous mode.
In fact, the client will do a `POST` request and the server will respond with an **Http code OK (200)** and the **request id** (i.e. uuid).

In order to inform the client of the processing status, there are several ways:

- **A bad solution:**  The client does a dirty check by polling on a `getStatus()` endpoint in order to verify the processing status, so he can retrieve results.
- **Nice to have solution**: Using a publish/subscribe over an **EAI**. The client will subscribe to some notification flow type and he will be notified over the **EAI** by the server once processing is done. However, the **EAIs** such ***Apache Camel*** does more than our need. In fact, Client and server are in the same company, they will communicate using the same protocol basically HTTP, hence, no need for language/protocol transforming.
- **A cleaner and light solution (In my point of view)**:  In addition to the **request id** rendered after the client **POST** request, we include a **callback endpoint** that the client should expose dynamically. This endpoint will be invoked once the heavy processing is done.

***Question:***

1. Have you experienced a such requirement? How did you solve it?
2. Are there any drawbacks to the third solution? (other than the constraint imposed to the client of being coupled to the server)

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: I guess your client isn't a Web app, otherwise I'd have proposed WebSockets. Aside the third solution seems wise if correctly done. But actually I don't see any reason to not make this callback endpoint permanent so that every async result is ever pushed there and you just have to filter on uuid to know what has just been finished. Dynamic exposure of "endpoints" seems to be a hard path, make it static and push events there.

Comment: polling is okay - [there's essentially support for it with regular http status codes](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/04/http-status-201-created-vs-202-accepted/).  Point 3 has problems if it's every exposed externally and you're using regular HTTP calls, since it can be used for reflection attacks (call service, give it some other target).  Note that something like WebSockets or gRPC, which can do bidirectional calls, maintain themselves via a heartbeat, or close the connection.